# AWS IOT Device provisioning through AWS IOT sdk javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, x509certificate, aws-iot

I'm trying to provision devices through AWS IOT api calls, i have used the AWS CLI to get CA Certificate and i have also generated X.509 certificate. Can anyone please guide me on how to Create Thing and attach certificate through SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully used the API to create devices on AWS IoT Core by following these steps.
Using the CLI i made CA certificate using rsa key

- openssl genrsa -out certs/rootCA.key 2048
- openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key certs/rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out certs/rootCA.pem
- aws iot get-registration-code (registrationCode used later as a "Common Name")
- openssl genrsa -out certs/verificationCert.key 2048

Then i created a CSR

- openssl req -new -key certs/verificationCert.key -out certs/verificationCert.csr
- openssl x509 -req -in certs/verificationCert.csr -CA certs/rootCA.pem -CAkey certs/rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out certs/verificationCert.crt -days 500 -sha256

Registered the CA Certificate

- aws iot register-ca-certificate --ca-certificate file://certs/rootCA.pem --verification-certificate file://certs/verificationCert.crt --allow-auto-registration
- aws iot update-ca-certificate --certificate-id e3f0a30c3bbd4c9fdbb752cf2717fda21fbd2f8158e5dc0bb320c8bdbabf6295 --new-status ACTIVE

Then i used the the verificationCert.csr for createCertificateFromCsr and used the certificateArn from response in attachPolicy and attachThingPrincipal

Answer (score 0):

You cant connect a device to AWS IoT with an API if you are trying to use HTTPS.  AWS IoT specifically requires the MQTT broker on AWS IoT Core.  Are you using this with a device like RPi?

Comment: Hi, im trying to create Thing using AWS IoT sdk. And i have managed to create Thing and now i was trying to attach certificate and policy.